# How to pass data from static context?

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following error on `Shopping.this`:

> non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context.

How should I change my code besides changing `getShipping()` to non-static?

```
public class Shopping extends Activity {
   public static final String total_weights = "weight";

    public static double getShipping(double total_weight) {
        String weight = Double.toString(total_weight);
        System.out.println(weight);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Shopping.this,shopping1.class);
        intent.putExtra(total_weights, weight);
        Shopping.this.startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```

Comment: add context as parameter to your helper method. You might want to make its return type void as well

Comment: try using getApplicationContext() instead...

Comment: getApplicationContext() cant be use as well, get the same error